# How do I sort a QList of QDateTime*?

Tags: qt, sorting, qdatetime

How do I sort a QList of QDateTime* objects by the value of the QDateTime object?

Comment: If you want to sort by the content of the QDateTime, and not the pointer values, then you should say so.  Otherwise the trivial answer is simply `qSort(list)`;

Comment: My fault, I want to sort by the value, I've edited the question

Comment: There is no need to handle QDateTime edits as pointers, better use a QList<QDateTime>.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`qSort`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtalgorithms.html#qSort-2) with your own comparison function:

```
#include <QtAlgorithms>

bool dtcomp(QDateTime* left, QDateTime *right) {
  return *left < *right;
}

QList<DateTime*> dtlist = ...;
qSort(dtlist.begin(), dtlist.end(), dtcomp);
```